# Is there a way to lengthen the lifespan of my strings?

Tags: guitar, maintenance, strings

I have acidic fingers and my strings wear out rather quickly. I am using Elixir which is a lot better than most other brands, but after around two weeks it loses the clean sound, becomes hard (or impossible) to tune perfectly, no matter how much I clean it after playing. I also use this thing on the strings before&after playing:

[image]

It does seem to help a bit, but not much. Is there something I can apply to my fingers or the strings to mitigate the acidity of my skin? Or any other practice which helps?